# (mismatching_state) CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response in django and google-api

Tags: python, django, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I'm creating a web page in django which uses google api in order to send a pdf file to google drive. Everything was working perfectly on my local machine but as soon as i put it on production i got an error ((mismatching_state) CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response.) as you can see down below.

[image]

Here is the function which sends the request:

```
def send_drive(file_name, file_path):
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = '/home/djuka/reusabletechnologies/project_app/reBankMini/reBankMiniApp/client_secret_156600557463-8e2qka5c4t646t7t4ksmbluo3aovv4q6.apps.googleusercontent.com.json'
    API_NAME = 'drive'
    API_VERSION = 'v3'
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

    # Upload a file
    file_metadata = {
        'name': file_name,
        'parents': ['1WpY7cw3S5RAPvCfFyPMDkw0I3vIZfQ_c']
    }

    media_content = MediaFileUpload(file_path, mimetype='application/pdf')

    file = service.files().create(
        body=file_metadata,

        media_body=media_content
    ).execute()

    print(file)
```

And `Create_Service()` function is in Google.py:

```
import pickle
import os
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import Flow, InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload, MediaIoBaseDownload
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from datetime import datetime


def Create_Service(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, *scopes):
    print(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, scopes, sep='-')
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file  
    API_SERVICE_NAME = api_name
    API_VERSION = api_version
    SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]
    print(SCOPES)

    cred = None

    pickle_file = f'token_{API_SERVICE_NAME}_{API_VERSION}.pickle'
    # print(pickle_file)

    if os.path.exists(pickle_file):
        with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as token:
            cred = pickle.load(token)

    if not cred or not cred.valid:
        if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
            cred.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            cred = flow.run_local_server()

        with open(pickle_file, 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(cred, token)

    try:
        service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
        print(API_SERVICE_NAME, 'service created successfully')
        return service
    except Exception as e:
        print('Unable to connect.')
        print(e)
        return None

def convert_to_RFC_datetime(year=1900, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0):
    dt = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0).isoformat() + 'Z'
    return dt
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is inteded for installed aplicatons

```
InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
```

By deploying it to a server it is trying to open the consent screen on the server.   What you need to do is open the consent screen on the users browser window.

You need code designed to run on a web server.

```
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow

# Use the client_secret.json file to identify the application requesting
# authorization. The client ID (from that file) and access scopes are required.
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'client_secret.json',
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'])

# Indicate where the API server will redirect the user after the user completes
# the authorization flow. The redirect URI is required. The value must exactly
# match one of the authorized redirect URIs for the OAuth 2.0 client, which you
# configured in the API Console. If this value doesn't match an authorized URI,
# you will get a 'redirect_uri_mismatch' error.
flow.redirect_uri = 'https://www.example.com/oauth2callback'

# Generate URL for request to Google's OAuth 2.0 server.
# Use kwargs to set optional request parameters.
authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
    # Enable offline access so that you can refresh an access token without
    # re-prompting the user for permission. Recommended for web server apps.
    access_type='offline',
    # Enable incremental authorization. Recommended as a best practice.
    include_granted_scopes='true')
```

Comment: "You need code designed to run on a web server." , Can you help me find? I was looking for a solution the whole day and can't manage to find anything.

Comment: [web-server#obtainingaccesstokens](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#obtainingaccesstokens)  Check the python sample might get you started.   or try checking this [#issue 755](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/755)

Comment: I managed to do something but now i get an error: (invalid_grant) Malformed auth code.
because of this line of code: flow.fetch_token(code=authorization_response)